# call a function in a component from another component

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, components, listener

In Angular2 , assume I have component1(use it as left panel navigator) and component2 .these two components are not related to each other (sibling, parent and child, ...).
how can I call a function in component1 from component2?
I cant use event binding here.

Comment: You'd probably use a [service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) to manage that connection.

Comment: Use the flux pattern - the service is the dispatcher of events, components are the subscribers.  Components don't really know about each other. This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219858/how-can-i-maintain-the-state-of-dialog-box-with-progress-all-over-my-angular-2-a/42221273#42221273

Comment: @ryannjohnson in component1, I have interpolation {{total}} which needs to be updated and shown in left panel immediately . if I just call service , how can I update this variable?

Comment: @pixelbits I will check if I can use it or not?

Comment: @SarahN Checkout @seidme's answer below. Once you've injected the service into your component, you can just refer to its properties directly in your template, ie `{{ myservice.total }}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use angular BehaviorSubject for communicating with non related component.

**Service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class commonService {
    private data = new BehaviorSubject('');
    currentData = this.data.asObservable()

    constructor() { }

    updateMessage(item: any) {
        this.data.next(item);
    }

}
```

**First Component**

```
constructor(private _data: commonService) { }
shareData() {
      this._data.updateMessage('pass this data');
 }
```

**Second component**

```
constructor(private _data: commonService) { }
ngOnInit() {
     this._data.currentData.subscribe(currentData => this.invokeMyMethode())
}
```

Using above approach you can invoke a method/share data easily with non related components.

[More info here](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2018/02/share-data-between-non-related.html)

Comment: But you have added the method in ngonit.
this will only occur once

Answer (score 2):

Shared service is a common way of communication between non-related components. 
Your components need to [use a single instance of the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2), so make sure it's provided at the root level.

Shared service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    componentOneFn: Function;

    constructor() { }
}
```

Component one:

```
export class ComponentOne {

    name: string = 'Component one';

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
        this.sharedService.componentOneFn = this.sayHello;
    }

    sayHello(callerName: string): void {
        console.log(`Hello from ${this.name}. ${callerName} just called me!`);
    }
}
```

Component two:

```
export class ComponentTwo {

    name: string = 'Component two';

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
        if(this.sharedService.componentOneFn) {
            this.sharedService.componentOneFn(this.name); 
            // => Hello from Component one. Component two just called me!
        }
    }
}
```

This post might be helpful as well: [Angular 2 Interaction between components using a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958836/angular-2-interaction-between-components/41960007#41960007)

Comment: Does this still work 10/24/2017? Tried it exactly as specified but the name from comp1 appears undefined when called from comp2.