# Angular2 : how to call main component function from a child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-components

How to call main component function from a child component when I have deep nested hierarchy?

[image]

I have 3 components, button component I'm including inside browser component and browser component I'm including inside main component.

On click of button I need to call a function which is inside main component.

**Button Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cb-button',
    templateUrl: 'cb-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['cb-button.component.scss']
})

export class CbButtonComponent {

     @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

     onBtnClick(): void {
        this.onClick.emit();
    }
}
```

**button component html**

```
<div (click)="onBtnClick()">
    <button>btn</button>
</div>
```

**browser component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'topology-browser',
    templateUrl: 'topology-browser.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['topology-browser.component.scss']
})

export class TopologyBrowserComponent {

   @Input('campus') campus: Campus;
}
```

**browser component html**

```
<div>
<h1>browser title</h1>
<cb-button (click)="editCampus()"></cb-button>
</div>
```

and finally in main component i'm including browser component

**main-component.ts**

```
editCampus() {
  alert('clicked');
}
```

**html**

```
<topology-browser [campus]="campus"></topology-browser>
```

when I click button I'm getting below error

**Errorself.parentView.context.editCampus is not a function**

Comment: You should use a shared service if you want to pass data several layers deep

Comment: Preferred method is use a shared service and inject it in the child constructor.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/42405146/3103979

Answer (score 3):

- If you know what type the root component is, you can use Pengyy's method.
- If you don't know what type in advance but you can customize the root component to your needs, a shared service is a good way.
- A more generic way is to get the root component by injecting `ApplicationRef` (not actually tested myself):

```ts
constructor(app:ApplicationRef, injector: Injector) {
  app.components[0].someMethodOnMainComponent();
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html

Answer (score 2):

As I know there are two ways for your situation:

- `inject` the parent component to child component
- use `EventEmitter`

Since you have more than two layers, injecting `MainComponent` to `ButtonComponent` is much more simply to implement:

```
import {Component, Inject, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';

// change the MainComponent to your real component name
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => MainComponent)) private main:MainComponent)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `forwardRef` if `ButtonComponent` and `MainComponent` are not declared within the same file.

Comment: The import you've used is for beta :-)

Comment: @echonax oops, sorry for I just copied from an simple test app which been made a long time ago, I'll update for that, thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer did i misunderstood something about `circular dependency`?, I have been keep this in mind after read this issue.https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3216

Comment: @Pengyy according to the doc skipping self will resolve the circular dependency with `@SkipSelf` and you can put an `@Optional` for a null check. So it would be something like `constructor(@Skipself() @Optional() private main:MainComponent)` More info on: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-the-parent-in-a-tree-of-parents

Comment: The comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3216#issuecomment-169325097 (and the one below that seem to say the same what I said in above comment).

Answer (score 0):

```
export class CbButtonComponent {

     @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

     onBtnClick(): void {
        this.onClick.emit('clicked');
    }
}
```

In your browser component

HTML

```
<div>
    <h1>browser title</h1>
    <cb-button (onclick)="buttonclicked($event)"></cb-button>
</div>
```

Component

```
@Output() buttonClick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

buttonclicked(clickedEvent){
   this.buttonClick.emit('clicked');
}
```

In your parent Main component

```
<topology-browser [campus]="campus" (buttonClick)="buttonComponentClicked($event)"></topology-browser>
```

Component code

```
buttonComponentClicked(buttonClicked){
       /// method calls goes her

}
```

**By this way you are notifying the browser component with the click which is captured again in the main component and handled**

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below. I have not tried this but am guessing it might work. The button component emits an event which is being caught by the main component.

You may also pass data via a common service and injecting that service into the child component and calling a service function which updates a service observable which is subscribed by the main component

**Your main component**

```
@Component({
  template `
    <button-comp (onClick)="mainMethod($event)"></button-comp>
  `,
  directives: [ ButtonComponent ]
})
export class MainComponent {
  (...)

  mainMethod(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

**your button component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cb-button',
    templateUrl: 'cb-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['cb-button.component.scss']
})

export class CbButtonComponent {

     @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

     onBtnClick(): void {
        this.onClick.emit('hello');
    }
}

button component html

<div (click)="onBtnClick()">
    <button>btn</button>
</div>
```