# call already existing component's method in another component

Tags: angular, typescript

**component 1**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component1',
    template:
    `
    <button (click)="submit()"></button>
    `
})
export class Component {

    constructor() { 
    }
    someMethod(): void {
    }
}
```

**component 2**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-component2',
        template:
        `
        <p>text</p>
        `
    })
    export class Component2 {

        constructor() { 
        }
    }
```

i want to  call the **component 1**  someMethod() from **component 2**

> **component 1** and **component 2** haven't any parent/child relation.

is there any way to get the instant of **component 1** in **component 2**

in java something like this

```
MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean("myClass");
```

is there any possible way like this in angular without `BehaviorSubject` and `EventEmitter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call a function in a component from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405038/call-a-function-in-a-component-from-another-component)

Comment: in there it has a parent-child relation. but here there are no relation. and i need to get a instant of component 1 in component 2

Comment: No, there is not. It is even mentioned in the question: _these two components are not related to each other (sibling, parent and child, ...)_. Notice the word 'not'. Also, the answer is providing you with a possible solution; using a shared service.

Answer (score 2):

You can forward component **A** to the other component **B** via the parent template that contains them. There is no repository of component instances that you can query. If you do not want to use the template to connect between the two, then you have to use a shared service instead.

app.component.html:

```
  <component-a #refA></component-a>
  <component-b [refA]="refA"></component-b>

  @Component({...})
  export class ComponentA {
      public someMethod() { }
  }

  @Component({...})
  export class ComponentB implement OnInit {
      @Input() refA: ComponentA;

      public ngOnInit() {
          if(this.refA) {
             this.refA.someMethod();
          }
      }
  }
```

The above has disadvantages.

- you can trigger a *this expression has changed after being checked* error.
- you need to mark the view in `ComponentA` as dirty if you mutate the component state form outside.

I don't recommend the above, because mutating the internal state of another component from outside the view is an anti-pattern. It is better to use a shared service and observables.

Answer (score -2):

I would just create a service that has a handle on the other component to where you can pass the reference point of that component into:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentService } from 'filepathofyourcomponentservice';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component2',
    template:
    `
    <p>text</p>
    `
})
export class Component2 {
    ViewChild('component) component: Component;

    constructor(private componentService: ComponentService) { 
        this.componentService.tapIntoComponent(this.component);
    }
}
```

Comment: He needs a reference to an instantiated component, not a new one.

Comment: If that's the case, he could use redux and a service to call the existing component.

Comment: here there are no relation between these components